# XXh model for $1/2$-spin chain

Tags: statistical-mechanics, integrable-systems

I'm looking for correlation function (i.e. $\langle  g \rvert \hat{S}_i^z \hat{S}_{i+n}^z\lvert g \rangle$, where $g$ stands for ground state) for given Hamiltonian($\hat{S}^z_i = \hat{c}^+_{j} \hat{c}^-_{j} - \frac{1}{2}$):
$$\hat{H} = \frac{-J}{2}  \sum_{j} \left(\hat{c}^+_{j+1} \hat{c}^-_{j}+ \hat{c}^{+}_{j}\hat{c}^{-}_{j+1} \right) + h  \sum_j \left(\hat{c}^+_{j} \hat{c}^-_{j} - \frac{1}{2}\right)$$
with periodic boundary condition and $\left\{ \hat{c}^-_{j} \hat{c}^+_{k} \right\} = \delta_{jk}$.

My first attempt was to diagnolize hamiltonian. Noticing that $\hat{U}\hat{H}\hat{U}^{-1} = \hat{H}$ we can use something like:
$$\hat{c}^\pm_{j} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum e^{ipj} \hat{a}^\pm_p$$
Where $p \in \frac{2\pi}{N} \left[0; N-1  \right]$. Noticing that $\{\hat{a}^+_p, \hat{a}^-_k\}=\delta_{pk}$. 
Upd: looking for corrleation function options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is a $\pm$ missing (in the exponent) when relating the original modes to to the Fourier-transformed ones, it should be: 
$$\hat{c}^\pm_{j} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{p \in \frac{2\pi}{N} \left[0; N-1  \right]} e^{\pm  ipj} \hat{a}^\pm_p.$$
Inserting this into the first term of the Hamiltonian, one obtains:
\begin{align}
\frac{-J}{2}  \sum_{j=1}^N \left(\hat{c}^+_{j+1} \hat{c}^-_{j}+ \hat{c}^{+}_{j}\hat{c}^{-}_{j+1} \right) 
&= \frac{-J}{2N} \sum_{p,p' \in \frac{2\pi}{N} \left[0; N-1  \right]} \sum_{j=1}^N  e^{i(p-p')j}\left(e^{ip}\hat{a}^+_p\hat{a}^-_{p'}+ e^{-ip'}\hat{a}^+_p\hat{a}^-_{p'}\right)\\
&= \frac{-J}{2N} \sum_{p,p' \in \frac{2\pi}{N} \left[0; N-1  \right]} N \delta_{p,p'} \left(e^{ip}\hat{a}^+_p\hat{a}^-_{p'}+ e^{-ip'}\hat{a}^+_p\hat{a}^-_{p'}\right)\\
&= -J \sum_{p \in \frac{2\pi}{N} \left[0; N-1  \right]} \cos(p)\,  \hat{a}^+_p\hat{a}^-_{p} ,
\end{align}
where, in getting the second line from the first, we used
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{N} e^{i(p-p')j} = N \delta_{p, p'}.
$$
Similarly, for the second term in the Hamiltonian (disregarding the constant term):
\begin{align}
h  \sum_{j=1}^{N} \hat{c}^+_{j} \hat{c}^-_{j}  &= \frac{h}{N} \sum_{p, p' \in \frac{2\pi}{N} \left[0; N-1  \right]}^{N-1} \sum_{j=1}^{N} e^{i(p-p')}\hat{a}^+_{p} \hat{a}^-_{p'} \\
&=\frac{h}{N} \sum_{p, p'  \in \frac{2\pi}{N} \left[0; N-1  \right]}^{N-1}  N \delta_{p,p'} \hat{a}^+_{p} \hat{a}^-_{p'}= h\sum_{p  \in \frac{2\pi}{N} \left[0; N-1  \right]} \hat{a}^+_{p} \hat{a}^-_{p}.
\end{align}
So in the end, we obtained the fermionic diagonalized Hamiltonian:
\begin{align}\hat{H} &= \frac{-J}{2}  \sum_{j=1}^N \left(\hat{c}^+_{j+1} \hat{c}^-_{j}+ \hat{c}^{+}_{j}\hat{c}^{-}_{j+1} \right) + h  \sum_{j=1}^N \left(\hat{c}^+_{j} \hat{c}^-_{j} - \frac{1}{2}\right)\\
&=  \sum_{p \in \frac{2\pi}{N} \left[0; N-1  \right]} \left( -J \, \cos(p)\,  \hat{a}^+_p\hat{a}^-_{p} + h\, \hat{a}^+_{p} \hat{a}^-_{p} -\frac{h}{2}\right).
\end{align}

[Note that in the derivation I used fermionic cyclic boundary conditions, i.e., $\hat{a}^\pm_{N+1} =\hat{a}^\pm_{1}$, which are not the same as the cyclic boundary conditions on a spin-chain after the Jordan-Wigner transformation.]

Comment: Am I actually right that $\frac{h}{2}$ will stand for ground state energy? This is awesome.

Comment: The ground state energy will have other components, as well. To obtain the ground-state, you have to fill all those $a^+_p$ (with $p \in \frac{2\pi}{N}[0;N-1]$) modes of the original Fock vacuum (, for which $-J \cos(p)+h <0$.

Comment: In other words, the ground state will be this: $\prod_{p; -J \cos(p) +h <0} a^+_p|0 \rangle$.

Comment: So let's take a look at $h>J$ case, where Fock vacuum is ground state. Evaluating correlation function through Wicks theorem I need to find $\langle 0 | \hat{c}^+ \hat{c}^- |0\rangle$ and it goes to norm of 0, yes?

Comment: @EzWin, yes in that case the ground state is the Fock vacuum, and one has $\langle 0| a^+_p a^-_p |0\rangle=0$ and $\langle 0| c^+_j c^-_l |0\rangle=0$. And to find $\langle 0| (c^+_jc^-_j -1/2)(c^+_{j+n}c^-_{j+n} -1/2) |0>$ you should just linearly expand and the use the Wick-rule, you will obtain that it is $1/4$.

Comment: That makes sense. One last question here, I think its small enough so not starting a new topic. Any tips on how to evaluate $\langle c^+_1 c^+_{n+1} \rangle$

Comment: @EzWin In the end, if you perform the thermodynamic limit, $N\to \infty$, you will end up with the following integral representations for such correlation functions $\langle c^+_j c^-_l \rangle=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{o}^{2 \pi} \, dp \, e^{-ip(j-l)}(1-\Lambda(p)/|\Lambda(p)| )$,  where $\Lambda(k)=-J \cos(p) +h$. In particular for the discussed $h>J$ case, for all $l$ and $j$, one gets $\langle c^+_j c^-_l \rangle=0$. Perhaps check out my paper on this (although it is much more general): https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.3112.pdf